# выборка из двух таблиц yii2 dataProvider

Tags: yii2

Есть две таблицы 
searchjur с полями:
id, id_selected_jur

и user c полями
id, name_user

Необходимо сделать выборку из двух таблиц
где searchjur основная и к ней прибавляем значение 
 name_user выбирается из user.id = searchjur.id_selected_jur
 не понимаю как их сдружить!

models/Findsearchjur

...

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Searchjur::find()->joinWith();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'id_pr' => $this->id_pr,
        'event_data' => $this->event_data,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name_event', $this->name_event]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = Searchjur::find();
...
$query->joinWith(['user']);

Дальше пользуемся через нотацию:
$query->andWhere(['user.id' => 12]);

PS: имейте ввиду что связька user у вас уже описано в модели

Например так:    

public function getUser()
{
   return $this->hasOne|hasMany(User::className(), ['id_selected_jur' => id']);
}
```

Comment: связьа user должна быть в модели user?

Comment: app\models\Searchjur has no relation named "user"

Comment: @ВикторВасильев, да, связька user должна быть в модели Searchjur

Comment: Спасибо, уже совсем близко, но пока не 100%.

Comment: Пишет:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.id_selected_jur' in 'on clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `searchjur` LEFT JOIN `user` ON `searchjur`.`id` = `user`.`id_selected_jur` WHERE `user`.`id`=61
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42S22
    [1] => 1054
    [2] => Unknown column 'user.id_selected_jur' in 'on clause'
)

Comment: Всё разобрался return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'id_selected_jur']);

Comment: Спасибо, Вам!!!

Comment: А не подскажете ещё такой вопрос, а как сделать, что бы из таблицы user выборка была отдельных столбцов, а не всей таблицы, сейчас он берёт всю инфу из таблицы user , а мне нужно  например только id и name_user

Comment: $query = Searchjur::find(['searchjur.*', 'user.id', 'user.name_user']); но он в массив всё= делает выборку всех столбцов

Comment: @ВикторВасильев, чтобы выбрать столбцы нужно после find() указать эти колонки в select: $query = Searchjur::find()->select(['searchjur.*', 'user.id', 'user.name_user'])

Answer (score 0):

если вам нужно отобразить данные в GridView или DetailView, то просто делайте так :

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'table.field'
    ],
]) ?>
```

где table - user, а field - id, или любое другое поле таблицы.